# Using IApplicationBuilder.Map generates nested paths with UseMvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying the new asp.net 5 alongside VSNET 2015 RC.

Configuration of my webapp:
Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 6.0.0-beta4

I'm really confused about this behavior:
if i use

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
 {
      ...
      app.UseMvc();
 }
```

everything works. I call my controller via
http://localhost:1234/api/values and all is ok.

For the sake of my testing if i change the snippet above in

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
 {
      ...
      app.Map("/api", api => {
         ...
         api.UseMvc();
       });
 }
```

and now every time I call the controller with the address above, the app returs 404.

Where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you're doing `app.Map`. What you're actually doing is adding a middleware to your HTTP pipeline which is saying: when an HTTP request comes in that matches the path `/api` here's what I want to happen.

You're then saying: I want MVC to run when a request satisfies the `/api` route. Since the configurations are nested the new path to your controller becomes: http://localhost:1234/api/api/values.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thank you!!! I didn't know about this behavior! Thank you again!!
FWIW: if on the controller class I change:
     [Route("api/[controller]")]
to
     [Route("[controller]")]
I can avoid the double "api/" in the address!