# Using RemoteAuthenticationHandler CallbackPath with IApplicationBuilder path match

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

*Related questions*

- [Using IApplicationBuilder.Map generates nested paths with UseMvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31117608/iapplicationbuilder-map)
- [CallbackPath implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49178819/callbackpath-implementation)
- [Redirect URI with Google using asp.net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33123586/redirect-uri-with-google-using-asp-net-mvc/35671214#35671214)
- [How to configure ASP.net Core server routing for multiple SPAs hosted with SpaServices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48216929/how-to-configure-asp-net-core-server-routing-for-multiple-spas-hosted-with-spase)

*Problem*

I have a service running under a specific path on a domain, e.g. https://www.example.com/myservice. The *myservice* path is dedicated to my service and other services have other paths at the same domain. It is setup like this in startup configure:

```
app.Map("/myservice", builder =>
{
    builder.UseStaticFiles();
    builder.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
});
```

I am using a library that implements a custom `RemoteAuthenticationHandler`. By default, the callback path routes to `/x-callback` which results in the browser trying to access https://www.example.com/x-callback.

Since my service does not process url's without the `/myservice` prefix I get a *404*. Changing the URL in the browser to `/myservice/x-callback` manually loads the callback and all is fine.

I can set the callback path for the handler in startup options as expected in startup configure services.

```
services.AddSomething(options =>
{
    options.AddThingX((o) =>
    {
        o.CallbackPath = new PathString($"/myservice{o.CallbackPath}");
    });
});
```

When I set the callback path like that the browser tries to load `/myservice/x-callback`. But, this URL now returns a *404*. It seems the handler for the callback also has its URL changed. Changing the URL in the browser to `/myservice/myservice/x-callback` loads the callback as expected.

*The RemoteAuthenticationHandler*

This is the code in the handler that handles the challenge and uses the callback path. It sets the callback path as a query parameter to the login url.

```
protected override Task HandleChallengeAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties)
{
    // Add options etc
    // ...
    // ...

    // This defines the login url, with a query parameter for the CallbackPath
    var loginUrl = GetLoginUrl(loginOptions);
    Response.Redirect(loginUrl);

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}

private string GetLoginUrl(MyServiceLoginOptions loginOptions)
{
    // This is where the return url is set. The return url
    // is used after login credentials are verified.
    return $"{Options.LoginPath}" +
            $"?returnUrl={UrlEncoder.Encode(Options.CallbackPath)}" +
            $"&loginOptions={UrlEncoder.Encode(_loginOptionsProtector.Protect(loginOptions))}";
}
```

*The login controller*

This is where the user can provide the credentials and have them verified. After verification, the user is redirected to the callback path.

```
private async Task<ActionResult> ChallengeComplete(LoginStatusRequest request, ChallengeResponse challengeResponse)
{
    // auth logic
    // ...
    // All is fine, the users credentials have been verified. Now
    // we can redirect to the CallbackPath.
    return Ok(Response.Finished(returnUri));
}
```

*Note*
I could do a URL rewrite but if possible, I would like to use the "correct" `/myservice` path to avoid confusion and perhaps causing issues for other services (though very unlikely).

*Question*

How can I prefix the callback path with `/myservice` so my application can process it without also adding the duplicate prefix?

Comment: Where's your call to `UseAuthentication`? It's not shown inside `Map`, so is it on the root `IApplicationBuilder`?

Comment: @KirkLarkin I'm using IdentityServer and it is inside `Configure` as you assume: `app.UseIdentityServer();`.

Comment: Disregarding the question and going right for a solution: would `o.CallbackPath = new PathString(o.CallBackPath);` work?

Comment: @LosManos Nice try! Unfortunately no work :P. It redirects to `/x-callback` and not `/myservice/x-callback`.

Comment: Is it `new PathString` that fools you then?

Comment: Can't see how. PathString only makes sure the string starts with `/` and does not end with `/`.

The issue is that MyService only processes requests in the pipeline under the `/myservice` path due to the mapping. When I add that prefix to the callback path, the pipeline processes the request but now the `RemoteAuthenticationHandler` is no longer listening at the "app root" but rather under `/myservice/identity`, which is under the mapped path in the pipeline. It then results in the /myservice/myservice/x-callback. Perhaps there is some event I could listen to, to intercept the request.

Comment: Can you share the code in `RemoteAuthenticationHandler`?

Comment: @Kahbazi Probably parts of it. Is there anything in particular you are after?

Comment: I wanna see the part that is using the `CallbackPath`

Comment: @Kahbazi Great! I added the relevant code I hope :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`MapMiddleware`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Http/Http.Abstractions/src/Extensions/MapMiddleware.cs) is adding the matched path to the `Request.PathBase`, so you can use it when creating the return url

```
string returnUrl = Context.Request.PathBase + Options.CallbackPath;
```